# Issue with multiple types in one declaration

Tags: c++, class, unix

When I try to compile i get the error:

```
In file included from editorMain.cpp:2:0:
EditorList.h:40:2: error: multiple types in one declaration
 };
  ^
In file included from EditorList.cpp:4:0:
EditorList.h:40:2: error: multiple types in one declaration
 };
  ^
EditorList.h:40:2: error: multiple types in one declaration
 };
  ^
```

The error is somewhere in this:

```
#ifndef EDITORLIST_H
#define EDITORLIST_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class EditorList

class Node
{
    friend class EditorList;
  private:
    Node *nextNode;
    int lineNum;
    string lineText;

  public:
    Node(void)
    : nextNode(NULL)
    {}

    Node(int val)
    : lineNum(val), nextNode(NULL)
    {}

    Node(int val,  Node* next)
    : lineNum(val), nextNode(next)
    {}

    int getLine(void)
    {return lineNum;}

    string getText(void)
    {return lineText;}

    Node* getNext(void)
    {return nextNode;}
};

class EditorList
{
  private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

  public:
    EditorList(void);
    EditorList(int val);
    //-EditorList(void);

    void insertHead(int val);
    void insertInside(Node* inptr, int val);
    void insertEnd (int);
    Node* getNode(int pos);
    void deleteLine (int);
    void printText ();
    void displayMenu ();
    void saveQuit (); 
};

#endif  /* EDITORLIST_H */
```

I really am not sure what is causing this as the only other time I have seen this error I had forgotten the semi colon after the class definition but that does not seem to be the case here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [OT]: `using namespace std;` is a bad idea, even more in header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I believe you need a ; after the class forward declaration.

```
using namespace std;

class EditorList

class Node
```

Should probably be

```
using namespace std;

class EditorList;

class Node
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing semi colon after the EditorList forward declaration